# Remove view on top or bottom of Uitableview hosted on Uitableviewcontroller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I am currently trying to remove the top or bottom view from my tableview but the size of the whole tableview isnt just right. Here is what i did so far.

- Created a TableviewController inside the Storyboard
- Created a Class    derived from UITableViewController and set
  everything up like    delegate etc.
- Dragged a view to the top of the tableview inside the Storyboard
- Created and connected an outlet named topview for this
- In Viewwillappear i will remove that topview dependent of some value so i tried some things

> ```
> -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
>     [super viewWillAppear:animated];
>     if(foo){
>         [self.topView setHidden:YES];
>         // or
>         [self.topView removeFromSuperview];
>         // or
>         [self.topView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
>     }
> }
> ```

For example if i remove the view from superview the topview isnt available anymore but there is a big gap on top .. how can i remove this top view from my tableview without having this gap ?

I put some Screenshots to describe my Problem:

[image: I want to change the size of topview or remove it completly]

[image]

Comment: Maybe after you remove your top view, you need to update your tableView's frame with new X, Y, Width and Height? I don't think iOS programming is quite like web programming where you remove a <div></div> and the other div automagically update :P Autolayout kinda behaves similarly but not quite as malleable as web programming elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put it inside the tableview it is probably the tableHeaderView. Try this:

```
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = nil;
```

Should remove the view and update the tableview accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

```
[self.tableview reloadData]
```

after removing topview or if you're using autolayout then you can use `[self.view updateConstraints];`